# spell:is-correct Marklogic API not working for a term

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have a term "9014(a" inserted into my dictionary file.

When I use spell:is-correct("/metadata/dict.xml","9014(a"),it is returning fn:false() even though the term is present in the dictionary.

the dictionary have other similar terms like 9(c.For this ,the API is returning true for this term.

Please give your suggestions on what may cause this issue.

Comment: The dictionary functions seem to behave oddly with words with non-alpha characters. I don't see anything in the documentation about this, so probably best to contact support.

Comment: @wst Thanks for the reply..I'll try contacting the support team :)